# Вывод на экран 15 случайных примеров из таблицы умножения

Tags: java

> Для проверки остаточных знаний учеников после летних каникул, учитель младших классов решил начинать каждый урок с того, чтобы задавать каждому ученику пример из таблицы умножения, но в классе 15 человек, а примеры среди них не должны повторяться. В помощь учителю напишите программу, которая будет выводить на экран 15 случайных примеров из таблицы умножения (от 2*2 до 9*9, потому что задания по умножению на 1 и на 10 — слишком просты). При этом среди 15 примеров не должно быть повторяющихся (примеры 2*3 и 3*2 и им подобные пары считать повторяющимися).

Что мне нужно добавить, чтобы доделать задачу? Как я думаю, осталось вывести уже отобранные задания на экран, но не знаю как это сделать.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] Mas = new int[15][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < Mas.length; i++) {
            for (int h = 0; h < Mas[i].length; h++) {
                Mas[i][h] = (int) (Math.random() * 8) + 2;
                if (h == Mas[i].length - 1) {
                    Mas[i][h] = Mas[i][h - 2] * Mas[i][h - 1];
                    for (int q = 0; q < i; q++) {
                        if (Mas[i][h] == Mas[q][h] && i > 0) {
                            if (Mas[i][h - 1] == Mas[q][h - 1] || Mas[i][h - 2] == Mas[q][h - 2])
                                --i;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что, например, можно сделать для решения задачи:

- сгенерировать массив/список из всех возможных комбинаций пар чисел
- случайно перемешать этот массив/список
- взять из него первые 15 элементов.

С использованием списка [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) и метода [Collections.shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) это выглядит так:

```
private static class Pair
{
    public int first;
    public int second;

    public Pair(int first, int second)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Pair> allPairs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int first = 2; first <= 9; first++)
    {
        for (int second = first; second <= 9; second++)
        {
            allPairs.add(new Pair(first, second));
        }
    }
    Collections.shuffle(allPairs);
    List<Pair> chosenPairs = allPairs.subList(0, 15);
}
```

---

Для вывода на экран переопределяем метод `toString` в классе `Pair`:

```
public String toString()
{
    return first + "*" + second;
}
```

После чего в основном методе просто выводим результирующий список на экран:

```
System.out.println(chosenPairs);
```

Пример вывода:

> [2*3, 4*6, 8*9, 6*6, 4*4, 2*7, 7*9, 3*9, 3*8, 3*3, 2*2, 9*9, 7*8, 4*8, 5*5]